# How to insert lines in a paragraph in Interop Word using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I'm trying to insert a paragraph after a specific line. I'm looping through the list of lines to print in the paragraph, the issue with my code below is, it only prints the last line from the list.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range r = para.Range;
r.InsertAfter("Insert below:" + "\n");
string style = "Normal";
object objstyle = style;
r.set_Style(ref objstyle);
foreach (List line in list_of_lines)
{
 r.Text = line.name.ToString()+":"+line.value.ToString();
 r.InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```

r.Text is overwritten each time and it only prints the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
r.Text = r.Text + line.name.ToString()+":"+line.value.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you Derek - It worked!, I didn't realize this. Sorry for asking another question here, I just noticed that I'm printing the "Insert below: " before this paragraph, rather than this I expect this paragraph to print after "Insert below: " which already exists in the document. Basically it is appearing twice. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is one of your lines in list_of_lines "Insert below:"?  Other than that, I don't really have any ideas.  You might want to ask another question and put a little more detail of what the word document (or portion of it ) looks like before and after you run your code.

Comment: No that was not one of the lines from list_of_lines..but anyways I figured out a solution for this. Thanks!